# JDialog Size Is Not Being Rendered

Tags: java, swing, jdialog

I created a JDialog in order to keep the window modal in order to stop the application from processing past a certain point. However, when I use this method, the box pops up, but the size is not being set to 400,400, it is appearing as if it has no size.

[image]

```
public class test {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    JFrame theDog = new JFrame();
    JButton theButton = new JButton("hello");
    //theDog.setSize(200, 200);
    JDialog thadialog = new JDialog(theDog,"theTitle", Dialog.ModalityType.APPLICATION_MODAL);
    thadialog.setVisible(true);
    thadialog.setSize(400,400);
    thadialog.pack();


    System.out.println("hello");
}
}
```

How to make the JDialog appear to have a size of 400,400 ?

Comment: Put `setVisible` after `pack()`.Try `dialog.setPreferredSize`

Comment: removed the pack and added this:         thadialog.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(400,400));
 .... still nothing

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `pack()` function tells a window to pack itself as small as possible to fit its components. It's a **different** way to set the size than calling the `setSize()` function.

By calling both `setSize()` and `pack()`, basically you're saying "first set your size to 400x400, then set your size to as small as possible."

In other words, if you want your window to be a specific size, then stick with the `setSize()` function. Get rid of the call to `pack()`.

Edit- You're also setting the dialog visible before you set its size. Since your dialog blocks the current thread, you don't even get to the `setSize()` function until **after** the dialog is closed. Move the call to `setSize()` to **before** the call to `setVisible()`.

Comment: i all ready tried it without pack, i added pack because the setSize wasn't working. I just commented it out and it still did not display

Comment: @simon You're setting your dialog visible before you set the size. Since the dialog blocks the thread, you never even get to the setSize() function until after the dialog closes. Move the setSize() call to above the setVisible() call.

Comment: thanks.. that worked. do you know why I cannot add items to the dialog? if i do thaDog.add(theButton); , it does not display the button the screen ?

Comment: @simon It's hard to say without seeing some code. You might consider posting an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) as a new question.